# Two verbs in a single sentence

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

> We must turn off the faucet and save water.

For the above construction, which of the below is more appropriate?

- Debemos cerrar el grifo y ahorrar el agua.
- Debemos cerrar el grifo y ahorramos el agua.

Comment: From my interpretation, one sentence is consequence of the other, so I would say: `Debemos cerrar el grifo para ahorrar agua.` or `Debemos cerrar el grifo y así ahorrar agua.`

Comment: As I comment below, if you use "para" to express causality, you are changing the original meaning of the sentence, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer is correct, but I think it will help you to know that your second proposed translation would fit better with an original sentence such as `We must turn off the faucet and save ourselves some water`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would translate the original sentence,

> We must turn off the faucet and save water.

as "Debemos cerrar el grifo y ahorrar agua", but more likely, as @fedorqui comments, I would write "Debemos cerrar el grifo para ahorrar agua", as "ahorrar agua" is the reason we must "cerrar el grifo".

Comment: I think your translation is better as you first propose it. The imprecision that you point out is also present in the original english sentence, so I think that shouldn't be removed. Else, it looks like you're really translating: "We must turn off the faucet to save water"

Comment: Well, that's the "literal" translation, and I said almost as much. But it's not the sentence I would write. I'm not a translator, so I can't really say what is better in this case.

Comment: Well, it's literal but that is only bad if you lose or change the meaning of the sentence on the literal translation. As I see it, in this case, you would be changing the meaning of it by not using the literal one. I guess we would need to know more about the context. However, I did upvote your answer, so don't take this as anything but a bit of nitpicking ;)

Comment: Lo más correcto sería : Debemos cerrar el grifo y ahorrar agua. No hay que poner el artículo delante de "agua".